# When there is no room to stabilize a nut, what then?

Tags: repair, furniture, hardware

I have an electric chair that someone cut the power cord and power pack from and are no longer accessible.  I'm removing the motor and one of the bolts in the frame to it spins relentlessly along with a locking nut that is supposed to be permanently fused to the frame (I know this because the other locking nuts are attached to the frame) but this one is not.  There is no room to put another wrench to the nut while loosening the bolt.  What is the best way to remove this particular bolt?  Not ready to give up on it but definitely need some suggestions.

Comment: I'm a nut and completely unstable.   That said, in the USA "electric chair" specifically means a device to kill people w/ high-voltage, high-current electricity.  Hoping that's not what you are mucking with.

Comment: A picture here would help greatly.

Comment: is there enough room to cut the bolt?

Answer (score 1):

I'd try simply wedging something in against the head of the bolt if you have any accessibility at all. Otherwise, an impact tool may break it loose even without support on the bolt. Often the inertia of the bolt's mass is enough to hold it against the tool's force.